# Bipartite graph matching like problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algorithms, vector-spaces, bipartite-graphs

Let $A=\{a_1,a_2, ..., a_n \}$ and $B=\{b_1,...,b_m\}$ be finite sets. Also $A_1,...,A_k\subset A$ are covering of $A$ and $B_1,...,B_t\subset B$ are covering of $B$. Let $V$ be a set of pairs of $A_xB_y$ so that for each $a_i\in A$ and $b_j \in B$ there is a $A_xB_y$ pair in $V$ and $a_i \in A_x,b_j\in B_y$.

This is similar to perfect matching in bipartite graphs but instead of single vertex we take some set of verticies  and match them another set. The question is what is minimal size of set $V$ so that perfect matching exists. We can take all $A_i$ and $B_j$ and since they are covering we will have the condition satisfied. But is will use $tk$ pairs.

Do anyone know some theory about this problem? I am thinking this may be reduced to bipartite graph matching problem. I need algorithm of finding minimal set $V$.

He is example:

Let $A=B=\{0,1,2\}$

$A_1=B_1=\{0,1\}$

$A_2=B_2=\{0,2\}$

$A_3=B_3=\{1,2\}$

If we take $V=\{A_1A_1,A_1A_2, A_2A_1,A_2A_2 \}$ the condition will be satisfied. All pairs will be covered.

$(0,0)\in A_1A_1$

$(0,1)\in A_1A_1$

$(0,2)\in A_1A_2$

$(1,0)\in A_1A_1$

$(1,1)\in A_1A_1$

$(1,2)\in A_1A_2$

$(2,0)\in A_2A_1$

$(2,1)\in A_2A_1$

$(2,2)\in A_2A_2$

You can see that $V=\{A_1A_2, A_2A_3, A_3A_1\}$ is the answer.

---

From comments it turned out that this problem is NP-hard so I am adding some conditions to get answer of my original problem.

Let $A=B$ and all $A_i$ have the same size. If we add this conditions it may be possible to give upper bound for $V$. In fact I am trying to get minimal cover of following graph:

Consider vector space $F_2^3$

$A=B=\{(000), (001), (010), (011), (100), (101), (110)\}$

$A_i$ is solution of equation. It is coset and contains $4$ vectors.

$A_1=\{x_1=0\}=\{(000), (001), (010), (011)\}$

$A_2=\{x_2=0\}$

$A_3=\{x_3=0\}$

$A_4=\{x_1+x_2=1\}$

$A_5=\{x_2+x_3=1\}$

$A_6=\{x_1+x_3=1\}$

$A_7=\{x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}$

I have showed that covering with size $6$ exists and need help to prove that it is minimal. Here is covering:

$V=\{A_7A_3, A_3A_4, A_5A_1, A_2A_5, A_1A_7, A_7A_2 \}$

Comment: You have written " The question is what is minimal size of set V so that perfect matching exists". Isn't it always exist?

Comment: I find the first paragraph opaque. Perhaps don't use $i$ and $j$ both for indices for the $A_i,B_j$ and $a_i,b_j$, since they don't have the same sizes?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I edited and added an example.

Comment: I think if you find minimal covering of $A$ and minimal covering of $B$ you can find minimal set $V$. But as I know (maybe I'm wrong) it can't be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: @user121270 You are right, minimum set cover is NP-hard

Comment: @user121270 I was thinking about that, but if we take all pairs of minimal coverings it will not give minimal answer. I have an example.

Comment: If so I think Ashot's problem is NP-hard too.

Comment: @user121270 Yes the OP problem is Np-hard, minimum set cover can be easily reduced to it in polynomial time. If you start with a set $S$, you just set $A = S$ and $B = \{x\}$ (any singleton), and a solution to the original problem would give a solution to the minimum set cover.

Comment: Ashot can you show your example, please.

Comment: @user121270 I edited. Please look at last line.

Comment: I see Ashot, but anyway, @alejopelaez showed that minimal covering problem can be reduced to your problem in polynomial time, so I think your problem NP-hard too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write $A_i$ as sets of numbers:
$$
A_1=\{0,1,2,3\}\\
A_2=\{0,1,4,5\}\\
A_3=\{0,2,5,6\}\\
A_4=\{2,3,4,5\}\\
A_5=\{1,2,5,6\}\\
A_6=\{1,3,4,6\}\\
A_7=\{0,3,5,6\}\\
$$
(I hope I have calculated everything right:)).
It's easy to see that $A_i \cup A_j\ne A$, so every number must be in at least $3$ "left component" sets, so if number of pairs is $k$ we have $$4k\ge21$$ so $k\ge6$.

Comment: Why must every number be in at least 3 left components? It may be in only one left component that is paired with 3 right components which cover right set.

Comment: It's mean it's in at least $3$ "left component" sets.

Comment: Ok, Now I understand, Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.